# "Object Required" when setting Active.Sheet to Range

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have tried about every solution that I could find.

What I am trying to do is run a Function for selected range (The ActiveSheet)
I can't even get to the looping part because it errors on line 5 (arc = ActiveSheet.Row.Count). The error it throws is "Object Required". I have tried several different solutions found online with no luck. I am a complete noob at excel vba (my background is vb.net and c#). I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction on what going wrong. Thanks in advance :)

```
Sub TestV2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range
Dim arc As Range
Set arc = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
Set selectedRange = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
For Each rng In selectedRange.Cells
If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
FireValidate
End If
    Next rng
    End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you declared `arc as Range` but you are trying to assign a `Long` number to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Set` keyword is required in VBA, to assign *object references*.

> ```
> Set arc = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
> Set selectedRange = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
> ```

Both `arc` and `selectedRange` are declared `As Range`, which *is* an object type - so the `Set` keyword is correct.

The problem is with the expressions on the right-hand side of the assignment operator: `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` evaluates to a `Long` integer, which is *not* an object type. `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` gets you the number of rows on the `ActiveSheet`, ...which should be the same number regardless of what specific sheet is currently active (all sheets have the same number of rows).

Hence, *object required*: you can't legally assign a `Range` object reference to a `Long` integer value; you need the right-hand side expression to evaluate to an *object reference*.

[Tim Williams' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940873/1188513) shows how you can correctly assign the `selectedRange` to the `Application.Selection`, assuming what's currently selected is a `Range` object (a *type mismatch* error will occur if that's not the case).

> *What I am trying to do is run a Function for selected range (The ActiveSheet)*

`ActiveSheet` doesn't return the *selected range* - it gives you the *sheet* that's currently active.

> *I am a complete noob at excel vba (my background is vb.net and c#)*

You can reference the Excel object model from VB.NET or C# as well, and automate Excel through Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) if you're more comfortable with these more powerful .net languages - but the object model will behave identically.

Comment: Nicely explained. Regarding `what's currently selected is a Range object (a type mismatch error will occur if that's not the case).` Use this for that `If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then Set selectedRange = Selection`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the current selection then:

```
Set selectedRange = Selection
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to modify your code as follows:

```
Sub TestV2()
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Selection
If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    FireValidate
End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in your code:

.1. **The key error**. Use **ActiveSheet.Rows.Count** directly may encounter "Object Required" exception, instead, you can use the following worked code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
'MsgBox ws.Rows.Count
Set arc = ws.Rows.Count
```

2. As **hod** said(this is not the key issue, but need to fix),

> You're getting this error because you declared arc as Range but you are trying to assign a Long number to it.

3. As **William** have pointed, you can use the **Set selectedRange = Selection** directly if you want to operate the selected range.

Sub TestV2()

```
Dim rng As Range

Dim selectedRange As Range
  Set selectedRange = Selection
    For Each rng In selectedRange.Cells
      If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
       'FireValidate
       'MsgBox "OK"
       End If
     Next rng    
End Sub
```

And I think most time we just need the **UsedRange.Rows** but not the **Rows** all.

**ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count** for the current sheet.

**Worksheets("Sheet name").UsedRange.Rows.Count** for a specific sheet.